# Setting a SQL variable equal to column in UPDATE with xml

Tags: sql-server, xml

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong here?
I would like to set the value of the variable @Customer to a value of a column in the same row.    I am assuming I am out of scope or something.    The  tag gets inserted but it is blank.  If I manually set @customer to something, then it does get populated in the xml.    There HAS to be a way to do this.

```
 Declare @Customer varchar(500)
 UPDATE Ore.RuleInfo
 set @Customer=RG.[RuleGroupName], UserEntryXML.modify('
    insert 
    <CustomerName>{sql:variable("@Customer")}</CustomerName> 
into (UserEntry/Results/Customer)[1]')
 From
 Ore.RuleInfo RI
 inner join ORE.RuleGroup RG on RG.RuleGroupID = RI.RuleGroupID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using sql:variable, use sql:column

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (x XML, customerName VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @tbl
        ( x, customerName )
VALUES  ( '<id>1</id><name>old1</name>', 'customer1' ),
( '<id>2</id><name>old2</name>', 'customer2' ),
( '<id>3</id><name>old3</name>', 'customer3' );

SELECT *
FROM @tbl


UPDATE @tbl
SET x.modify('
    replace value of (/name/text())[1]
    with sql:column("customerName")
    ')

SELECT *
FROM @tbl
```